# Conditionally conjugate prior in heteroskedastic model

Tags: regression, bayesian, linear-model, heteroscedasticity, conjugate-prior

I am researching a linear model where the noise is a function of the slope parameter as follows

$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \beta_1\epsilon_i$$
$$\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2 g)$$

where $g$ is known. If reparameterized slightly so that
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1p_i$$
$$p_i \sim N(x_i, \sigma^2g)$$

it reminds me of model (2) in [Gelman 2006](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bayesian-analysis/volume-1/issue-3/Prior-distributions-for-variance-parameters-in-hierarchical-models-comment-on/10.1214/06-BA117A.full) which he defines as

$$y_{ij} \sim N(\mu + \xi\eta_j, 
\sigma^2_y)$$
$$\eta_j \sim N(0, \sigma_{\eta}^2)$$

He says of the model that a conditionally conjugate prior distribution family for $\xi$ is normal and for $\sigma^2_{\eta}$ is inverse-gamma. My question is whether or not $\beta_1$ from my model has a conditionally conjugate normal distribution prior and $\sigma^2$ a conjugate inverse-gamma prior as well. It seems like the issue here would be if $x_i$ is not equal to 0. Would that prevent their from being a conjugate prior?

Comment: Are you sure the coefficient $\beta_{1}$ is multiplied with the error term $\epsilon_i$? Also, if $g$ is *known* (and constant?), why isn't it eliminate from the model? Finally, if you insist on a closed-form expression for the posterior (why though?), have a look at [Brorsen (1992)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0165-1765(92)90153-P).

Comment: This model isn't identified.  Multiplying $\epsilon_i$ by $\beta_1$ is the same as just increasing the variance of $\epsilon_i$ by $\beta_1^2$, leading to $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2\beta_1^2g)$.  No matter what $\beta_1$ is, you can find $\sigma^2$ that gives you any variance you want, so what's the point in including it?